# Pandas error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dateframe named Mj_rank, with date as Datetime and index which looks like this:

```
                A      B     C ...
date
2016-01-29     False  False  True
2016-01-30     False  False  True
2016-02-01     True   True   True
  ....
2017-12-29     False  True   True
```

Currently, the data is daily, but I would like to resample the data into a new df that contains every 6 months nth.

Therefore I did:

```
Mj_rank_s = Mj_rank.resample('6M').asfreq().tail()
```

which gives me this output:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

strangely enough, if I use other methods like max() or min() it works fine, but not "asfreq()".

I tried different ways based on existing stackoverflow suggestions like adding in front, but didn't work :

```
Mj_rank = Mj_rank.reset_index()
Mj_rank['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Mj_rank['date'])
Mj_rank = Mj_rank.set_index('date')
```

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
Thanks to @jezrael he pointed out I had problems with duplicates using
    Mj_rank[Mj_rank.index.duplicated(keep=False)]

Comment: It looks like bug/ not implemented for duplicated `date`s + `resample` + `asfreq` :(

Comment: So is possible remove dupes dates?

Comment: I'm pretty confident there are no duplicated dates, which makes it even more strange.

Comment: So `Mj_rank.index.is_unique` return True ?

Comment: And `Mj_rank[Mj_rank.index.duplicated(keep=False)]` mo rows?

Comment: Damn! output: False and I see duplicates!

Comment: Mj_rank[Mj_rank.index.duplicated(keep=False)]: also shows me 2 columns I haven't seen, one called level_0 and one called index

Comment: Why would you do both `resample` and `asfreq`?  Normally you'd do one or the other.  `resample` is a deferred action so (like groupby) and needs to be followed by something like max or min -- something that tells resample how to aggregate the data -- not asfreq, which is essentially redundant here.  Pandas behavior seems like what I'd expect here, unless I'm missunderstanding.

Comment: As I want the rows for every  6month and I therefore can't use max or min, it works by using asfreq() according to panda docs examples. I'm sure there is a better way to achieve the goal though :D.